# Referenciar a um import dinâmicamente

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Abaixo estou definindo alguns imports;

```
import users from './user';
import securities from './security';
import softwares from './software';
```

e quero poder acessar eles no decorrer do meu arquivo, mas só consigo acessá-los dinâmicamente se eu fizer isto:

```
const allCollections = {
  users,
  securities,
  softwares
};
```

desta forma eu consigo utilizar da forma que eu preciso:

```
function showImportDynamically(nameOfImportWanted) {
  console.log(allCollections[nameOfImportWanted]);
}
```

Tem como fazer isso sem precisar recorrer a criar um `Object()` contendo todos?
tentei usar o global.users, mas não deu certo. Tentei dar uma olhada na documentação para que se eu fizesse `import './users'` ele ficasse na memória mas não consegui capturá-lo. Abaixo o arquivo `./users` como exemplo:

```
const users = {
  fields: {
    state: {},
    city: {},
    name: {}
  }
};

export default users;
```

Comment: @handoncloud funciona muito bem, mas como eu acesso ele na função `showImportDynamically(arg)`  sem saber qual import eu quero usar? Apenas vou saber qual import usar quando for passado por argumento na função

Comment: Eu acho que para o que você quer, esta abordagem de usar um objeto é a melhor saída. Ou você pode usar o `require` (ao invés do import), que recebe uma string como parâmetro, permitindo, assim, setá-la dinamicamente.

Comment: @mrlew, vou ter que deixar assim então, já procurei outras formas(usar require funcionaria do jeito que quero), mas não quero largar mão de fazer todo meu projeto em ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei quase nada sobre a síntaxe de módulos implementada no ES6, embora tem uma visão geral de como ela funciona [nessa página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (mas geralmente a documentação do Mozilla é errada/incompleta na minha opinião...).

Na sua tentativa de usar `export default`, é possível obter o valor padrão exportado com essa síntaxe (como [exemplado aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export)):

```
import users from './users';
```

E se você não estiver usando exportação padrão:

```
import * as users from './users';
```

No TypeScript isso vai mover todas as exportações do módulo requirido num valor baseado em objeto, acessível numa variável `users` (apesar de que não sei que tipo de variável seria essa).